# Push Down NLA strips for only selected bones?

Tags: nla-editor

I have a whole sequence of lip sync animation and I am now going through and adding in all the other secondary face and head animation on top of it. I want to have a cyclic head bobbing that I can turn on and off at different points in the sequence. Using the F-curve modifier to cycle it doesn't allow me to only cycle specific frames, so I decided to try an NLA strip, which admittedly I am not very familiar with yet.

The issue is that when I hit "Push Down" to convert the head bob on the selected bones into an NLA strip, it applies the NLA to the entire rig at once, lip sync and all, rather than just the selected part. I just want to NLA a specific group of bones, and leave all my others as is.

Is there a way to do that? Or did I screw myself by not following the order properly and making the NLA for the head before I went in and did a bunch of more complicated stuff, and I'll need to figure out another way?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new action in the *Dope Sheet*, keyframe only the lips bones, push down the action into the NLA, it should play with the head action.

Comment: Ok I see how that works now, sorry if this was an obvious question, just couldn't find this scenario in tutorials. Thank you!